# Apache Beam KafkaIO BatchMode OOM issue

Tags: apache-spark, apache-kafka, batch-processing, apache-beam

I have a use case where I want to read data from `Kafka` in Batch mode using `Apache Beam` with Spark runner.

Using `withMaxNumRecords(long)` method of `KafkaIO` class, it is possible to make `BoundedReader` from `UnboundedReader`.  But what I found is that, in batch mode, data is first to read from each partition, put into memory and then passed to the next action (map, filter, etc).

I have huge data in each partition and while reading this data in batch mode, I am getting `OOM` error. I tried to increase executor memory.  But for each run, I can not configure this parameter with required value. 
Another thing is, I am able to read the same data in stream mode.

I think it is happening because in batch mode all records from each partition are assigned to `GlobalWindow` (part of ProcessContext), which is triggered only all data is read. This might because of the `OOM` issue.

If this is the reason, then how can I change `GlobalWindow` to `PartitioningWindow` in ProcessContext?

If this is not reason, then how can I read this huge data from Kafka in Batch mode using Apache Beam without increasing executor memory for each run?

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by executor memory ? Are you using Spark runner ?

Comment: @JayadeepJayaraman : yes I am using spark runner.

Answer (score 0):

From the documentation

```
You can use windowing with fixed-size data sets in bounded PCollections. However, note that windowing considers only the implicit timestamps attached to each element of a PCollection, and data sources that create fixed data sets (such as TextIO) assign the same timestamp to every element. This means that all the elements are by default part of a single, global window.

To use windowing with fixed data sets, you can assign your own timestamps to each element. To assign timestamps to elements, use a ParDo transform with a DoFn that outputs each element with a new timestamp (for example, the WithTimestamps transform in the Beam SDK for Java).
```

Here is an example of how to define windows for a bounding dataset - https://beam.apache.org/get-started/wordcount-example/#unbounded-and-bounded-datasets

Also from the documentation a bounded dataset is read all at once and assigned a Global Window as described below

```
The bounded (or unbounded) nature of your PCollection affects how Beam processes your data. A bounded PCollection can be processed using a batch job, which might read the entire data set once, and perform processing in a job of finite length. An unbounded PCollection must be processed using a streaming job that runs continuously, as the entire collection can never be available for processing at any one time.
```

I believe to solve your problem you can try setting a window for the bounded collection and try to run it on Cloud Dataflow to see if this works or not. You can also refer to the beam capability matrix to see what is supported from a Spark Runner perspective.

Comment: Thanks Jaydeep for help.  About timestamp, if you check KafkaIO code, each record has its own create timestamp attached.  So it is not case that same timestamp is attached to all records and because of that all records belong to same window.
When I debug code, I found that by default GlobalWindow is assigned to ProcessContext object.  outputWithTimestamp() method of ProcessContext is used to output records, so all records are belonging to GlobalWindow.

Comment: Also in my use case, there is no aggregation operation and as per Beam documentation, window operation will be applied only there is groupBy() kind of operation is there next somewhere in pipeline.  So I don't think that though I use window() on my bounded pcollection, it won't be applied.